# how to manually provision juju on multiple servers

Tags: juju

Its been a while since I've been here here is the question...

I have three servers, 1 x86 and 2 x64. I did manage to get juju to load on a x86 server. How can I tell juju on the x86 that there are two more servers available for charms?

Essentially I am trying to make the x86 the conductor. ( I have tried to find the Ubuntu orchestra in 14.04 and cant seem to find it)

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Juju client is installed on your 'user-space' computer which can then get the Juju State Server up and running on one of your machines. To get all three of these machines in one *environment* you'll first want to get MAAS set up. Take a look at MAAS http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/maas whos documentation can be found here: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.5/install.html